# postman returning 404 for the node.js endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a simple rest endpoint using node.js.
I am following the tutorial https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2

the folder structure is notable/app/routes/ and the routes folder contains the index.js and note_routes.js files

I am able to run the command `npm run dev`, and the output shown is:

```
> notable@1.0.0 dev /Users/tejanandamuri/Desktop/notable
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
We are live on 8000
```

after this. in the postman, when I try to call the http://localhost:8000/notes, it is returning 404 error with the response body **Cannot POST /notes**

Here are my files:

**server.js:**

```
const express        = require('express');
const MongoClient    = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
const app            = express();
const port = 8000;
require('./app/routes')(app, {});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});
```

**index.js:**

```
// routes/index.js
const noteRoutes = require('./note_routes');
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  noteRoutes(app, db);
  // Other route groups could go here, in the future
};
```

**note_routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
    // You'll create your note here.
    res.send('Hello')
  });
};
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "notable",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my first rest api",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.28"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "venkata",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting up all your routes in index.js, but there is no reference to index.js in server.js. You need to do something like  `var myRoutes = require('index.js')` and then `myRoutes(app, db)` in server.js to bind the routes to your app.

Answer (score 1):

Change line 6 in server.js to `require('./routes/note_routes')(app, {});`

This assumes your file tree looks something like this:

```
.
+--/node_modules // this contains a ton of sub-folders
+--/routes
+  +--index.js
+  +--note_routes.js
+--package.json
+--server.js
```

[image]

Comment: after I changed the path in require, it displayed the following error: Error: Cannot find module './note_routes'

Comment: Try changing it to `require('./routes/note_routes')(app, {});` didn't notice your mentioning of the folder structure.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri were you able to get this working? If so, please share your answer or mark the correct answer. This allows other users who encounter the same or a similar problem to more easily identify the correct solution without having to read all the discussions.